# Connect from Angular Docker container to Asp.Net container

Tags: asp.net, angular, docker, docker-compose

I created a simple program with three containers: database (MS SQL Server), backend (Asp.Net Core), and frontend (Angular 8).
To run it I use a docker-compose:

```
services:
    sqlserver:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        #ports:
            #- 1433:1433 - it's hidden
        volumes:
            - data-sql:/var/opt/mssql
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "Pass"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    
    web_api:
        build:
            dockerfile: WebApi/Dockerfile
        #ports:
            #- 5000:80 - it's hidden
        depends_on:
            - sqlserver
        environment:
            "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://+:5000"
            "ConnectionStrings:SqlConnectionString": "Server=sqlserver,1433;Database=db;User Id=sa;Password=pass;"
    
    web_app:
        build: WebApp/
        ports:
            - 4200:80
        depends_on:
            - web_api
        environment:
            "ENV": "Production"
            "BASE_URL": "http://web_api:5000"
```

I want to hide the external ports for `sqlserver` and `web_api`, because they are only used in the docker-compose services.

I could hide the `sqlserver` port by adding the `SqlConnectionString` environment to the `web_api`.

But this approach doesn't work with `web_app`. My idea was to add the `"BASE_URL": "http://web_api:5000"` to the `web_app` so it'll be able to send requests on this URL, but it doesn't work.

Have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because this kind of frontends (SPA) communicates with your backend not internally (docker network) but externally (your host network).

Accordingly, 2 steps are needed:

1. Backend must be accessible thru host network
2. Frontend should point to the public URL of backend

```yaml
    web_api:
        build:
            dockerfile: WebApi/Dockerfile
        ports: #  Added
           - 5000:80 #  Added
        depends_on:
        # ... etc
    
    web_app:
        build: WebApp/
        # .... etc
        environment:
            "ENV": "Production"
            "BASE_URL": "http://localhost:5000" #  Changed
```